# What is the meaning of writing a catalyst name with two compounds split by a hyphen?

Tags: nomenclature, catalysis

In literature, sometimes I see catalysts written with "-" between elements/compounds. Does this mean the first element/compound is supported on the second, or is the second a promoter? (e.g. $\ce{Fe}$-$\ce{KCl}$).

Comment: Can you give an example from literature? I only know it with a /. Pd/C is palladium on charcoal, Pd/MgO is palladium on MgO and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we consider palladium on carbon or alumina then it means that the palladium particles are dispersed onto the carbon or alumina. The carbon or alumina acts as a support for the catayltic particles of the palladium.

If we consider Lindlar's cataylst this can be written as Pd/CaCO3/Pb

The Pd (palladium) is the hydrogenation cataylist
The CaCO3 is the support
The Pb is a poison which is used to modify the chemistry of the palladium

Sometimes one of the things separated by a / line is either a promotor or a poison.

Comment: Could you cite some nomenclature sources? That would make your answer much more complete. Thanks!